PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function vc_set_default_editor_post_types() IN WORDPRESS
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
I have a WordPress website, using the TheFox theme, version 3.9.65, the latest version of WordPress, PHP 8, and I’m getting the following error. Any idea?
PHP Fatal error:
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function vc_set_default_editor_post_types() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/wp-content/themes/thefox/functions/vc-functions.php:32
This is what I have on that line
$list = array(
    'page',
    'post',
    'staff',
    'product',
    'portfolio',
);
vc_set_default_editor_post_types( $list );

I can’t access the site or the WordPress Admin. I only have access to the files and database.

sounds like probably a plugin is missing. https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/inner-api/vc_set_default_editor_post_types/ looks relevant
